# Check if a file exists on AWS S3 path using aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems, aws-sdk

I am trying to check whether a particular pdf file exists on AWS S3 using aws-sdk gem (version 2) inside ruby on rails application.

I have the AWS connection established and currently using **`exists?`** method:

```
puts @bucket.objects(prefix:"path/sample_100.pdf").exists?
```

on running the above statement, I get the below no method error:

```
undefined method 'exists?' for Aws::Resources::Collection
```

Checked few documents but of not much help. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bruno's answer is probably best answer if you want to check if a file outside your application exists. Yet if the file is uploaded from your application ( with paperclip, carrierwave, shrine..) the uploaded file is part of your application and exists in your application database, and this is easy to check.

Comment: @Maxence Thanks for the input. I figured out the solution. The pdf file that I am searching is stored in AWS S3 bucket and the application is using **aws-sdk gem** (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) to perform any such actions.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Bruno, you can use `head_object` to get info on the file, without actually fetching it. If it is not found (or other problems, such as permissions), an exception will be raised. So if `head_object` returns, the file exists.

Here's a file that exists:

```
> head = s3.head_object(bucket: bucket, key: path)
 => #<struct Aws::S3::Types::HeadObjectOutput last_modified=2020-06-05 16:18:05 +0000, content_length=553, etc...>
```

And here's one that does not exist, and the exception it raises:

```
> path << '/not-really'
 => "example/file/not-really"
> head = s3.head_object(bucket: bucket, key: path)

Aws::S3::Errors::NotFound

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):18
Aws::S3::Errors::NotFound ()
```

And here's how you can roll your own `s3_exists?` method:

```
def s3_exists?(bucket, path)
  s3.head_object(bucket: bucket, key: path)
  true 
rescue
  false
end
```

Comment: This solution also correctly identifies the presence of a zero-byte file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby developer myself, but I might be able to suggest something.

The usual way to check whether an object exists in Amazon S3 is using the [**HEAD Object**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) operation. Basically, it returns the metadata (but no content) of an object if it exists, or a 404 error if it doesn't. It's like GET Object, but without the contents of the object.

I just looked up in the AWS SDK for Ruby API Reference and found this method:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#head_object-instance_method

Take a look at that, it's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight.  I was basically trying to search pdf file on AWS S3 bucket and if it exists then perform further actions on it. **exists?** method worked for me.  
I just placed the aws file path in a variable and then called the exists method on it. This returns true when executed.
`file = "path/sample_100.pdf "`  `@bucket.objects(file).exists?`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use the much simpler S3 gem: https://github.com/qoobaa/s3 If you only need to deal with S3. You'll be able to do it this way:

`object = bucket.objects.find("example.pdf")`

Comment: Thank you @CV-Gate for the alternative S3 gem. I will surely give it a try. But the current application is already heavily using it.